# Loss on masked tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp

Suppose I have logits like

```
[[4.3, -0.5, -2.7, 0, 0],
[0.5, 2.3, 0, 0, 0]]
```

where clearly the last two in the first example and last three in the second example are masked (that is, they are zero) and should not affect loss and gradient computations.

How do I compute cross-entropy loss between this logits and corresponding labels? For sanity, the labels for this example can be something like

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

(One issue: Softmax, followed by log, on the logits will be applicable for the masked zeroes too and tf's cross-entropy method will consider the loss for those elements too.)

(Also, you can think about the problem like this: I have logits of varying lengths in a batch, i.e. my logits were length 3 and 2 for eg.1 and eg.2 respectively. Same is followed by the labels.)

Answer (score 6):

Masking the cross-entropy loss is a common operation, covered by the library. It actually handles the more general concept of weights; Provide binary weights for masking.

```
mask = tf.equal(logits, 0) # as in the OP
weights = tf.to_float(mask) # convert to (0, 1) weights
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(labels, logits, weights)
```

Don't compute softmax cross entropy by actually computing the softmax of the ouput then the cross-entropy, you loose the computational precision and stability of doing it simultaneously.

Comment: I actually needed regular softmax so I could sample from it, for which tf doesn't provide a weighted version.

Comment: Is this sampling part of the loss computation? If not, I would still suggest to go with `tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy` for the reasons listed above. You can still compute the softmax of the logits independently if you need to.

Comment: This also requires that the labels are one hot encoded. Where I need the sparse version. Which doesn't support weights. Also, I can't get your code to work.  https://pastebin.com/e1pL7B51

Comment: The sparse version does support weights as well (at least it does now, although it's a v1 compat so it probably has for a while now): https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/losses/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up doing was the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
prelim_scores=tf.constant([[4.3, -0.5, -2.7, 0, 0],[0.5, 2.3, 0, 0, 0]])
mask=tf.constant([[True,True,True,False,False],[True,True,False,False,False]])
dummy_scores = tf.ones_like(prelim_scores) * -99999.0  # the base matrix to choose from if dummy relation
scores = tf.where(mask, prelim_scores,dummy_scores)  # [B, MAX_NUM_ACTIONS]
a=tf.nn.softmax(scores)
with tf.Session() as sess:
   print(sess.run(a))
```

result is:

[[9.9094123e-01 8.1551941e-03 9.0362143e-04 0 0]

[1.4185105e-01 8.5814887e-01 0 0 0]]

credit goes to: [here](https://github.com/shehzaadzd/MINERVA/blob/7a6007084d3c4228aa2dc323baab57688586818c/code/model/agent.py)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
import tensorflow as tf
logits = [[4.3, -0.5, -2.7, 0, 0], [0.5, 2.3, 0, 0, 0]]
labels = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=logits, labels=labels))
```

Answer (score 0):

With TF2 one may be able to use indexing in this case.
That is what I end up doing.

```
mask = logits != 0 
weights = tf.cast(mask, tf.float32) 
labels = tf.cast(labels, tf.float32)
logits = tf.cast(logits, tf.float32)
tf.compat.v1.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(labels[mask], logits[mask])
```